# Segmentation Fault taking user input

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm running a simple infinite loop that needs to take in user input and split it into an array. When I try to display the elements of the array I get  a seg fault.
This is my code.

```
while(1){
        int tokenCount = 1;
        char* usrInputStr = NULL;
        char* buffer;

        scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", usrInputStr);

        int len = strlen(usrInputStr);

           for (int i = 0; i <len ; ++i) {
               if(isspace(usrInputStr[i])) tokenCount++;
           }

        char* currentTokens[tokenCount+1];
        int index = 0;
        buffer = strtok(usrInputStr, " ");
        while(buffer != NULL){
            currentTokens[index] = buffer;
            index++;
            buffer = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < index+1; ++i)
        {
            currentTokens[i];
        }


    }//end of backbone while

    return 0;
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong, the same code was working fine in a .cpp file, when compiled with g++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not allocated memory for `usrInputStr` after you initialized it with:

```
char* usrInputStr = NULL;
```

and then you proceed to use it in:

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", usrInputStr);
```

Comment: So do I need to malloc it?

Comment: That's one option. Other options are to use a sufficiently large array, or use `std::getline` (a C++ library function).

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory location to **char * usrInputStr** and scanning something to it which is actually a null pointer. which resulted you some segmentation fault error. You just assign some dynamic memory to it.
For Example:-

> char * usrInputStr = (char *) malloc (50*sizeof(char));